# Installing Windows 7 64-bit on AMD Turion64 X2

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

I had asked a [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/49166/is-amd-turion-64-x2-really-64-bit) about my AMD Turion64 C2 process. I wanted to install Vista 64bit on it but was not provided any options during install to select it. I was installing from MSDN disc(Which contained both 64 and 32-bit version).

Now we have got Windows 7 Enterprise DVD and again I'm in the same thing. I've installed it twice and it still is 32-bit. I created VPC and it is installing 32-bit on it.

I want to try Sharepoint 2010 beta and can't do it without 64-bit Windows.

Here is a SecurAble description of my system:

[image]

Comment: Where did you get a windows 7 disk that claims to be both 64 and 32 bit? (link please)?

Comment: It does not say. Okay it might be the case that the disk is actually 32-bit. I remember we got different DVDs for Vista 64bit. But few days back we got some promotional stuff form MS and a DVD. I opened it today and it is Server 2008 R2 Foundation and this truly is 64-bit. But it says that my machine is incompatible. Is it AMD F* people or HP doing the funny things? (I've HP Pavilion db6000 laptop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the list of ISOs available to me on MSDN, I can't see any versions of Vista or 7 that package both 32 and 64-bit into the same disk. That said, your MSDN entitlements may differ.

I suggest trying a dedicated x64 installation media. On MSDN that's:
en_windows_7_enterprise_x64_dvd_x15-70749.iso
en_windows_7_professional_x64_dvd_x15-65805.iso

Just to save you any further frustration, I'm not sure Sharepoint 2010 will run from 7 or Vista, even the 64-bit builds. I believe Server 2008 x64 is required.

Comment: In some way your solution helped @Chris. I tried dedicated media to boot directly and install OS and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, it is not very nice feeling, but the case is that I'm an idiot. I had 32-bit OS and in that I am installing 64-bit virtual machine :(

I simply booted from 64-bit dvd and am running 2008 R2 64-bit server now!

Thanks for all your help.